# Trimming down Liferay: Removing Hibernate and other unused applications

Tags: hibernate, liferay

I have some questions related to interaction of Liferay with hibernate. We for some reasons want to eliminate this layer from the application. Hence the below questions:

I know that Liferay is packaged with Hibernate and the access to data in Liferay database is simplified by using the Hibernate API.

1. To what extent does it depend on it?
2. Can it be unplugged?
3. How much development effort would be required on it?
4. For what purpose does liferay use its internal database?

Primarily we basically want to remove almost everything that isn't required for our purpose.

P.S.: I couldn't find an appropriate link which answers the above and hence here.

Comment: Well the thing is open source, so you can have a look and decide for yourself.  I'd say it's doable but I would strongly recommend against it because by performing this kind of surgery you cause a lot of maintenance work for yourself down the line.  Could it be that you feel the need to drastically trim down the software because it's actually not a good match to your requirements?

Comment: Actually on paper our application looks a lot heavy weight. And also Liferay inbuilt comes with a lot of stuff which are not required.

Comment: from bitter personal experience cutting up liferay and attempting to change internals is very hard and time consuming.

Comment: The good news is that if you don't use a feature, the tax is pretty low, liferay will of course end up using hibernate as seem to remember it uses it to read it's configuration from the DB.

Comment: @GarethDavis In the link http://www.bluhm-de.com/setting-up-a-liferay-server-on-standard-fedora-12-tomcat6 at end there is phase to turn off hibernate. If so how will sql and all will be taken care.. ? On its own.. or will it requires some effort to keep in place.. those queries

Comment: Plain and simple, It's not straight forward (AFAIK, its not possible) to remove hibernate from Liferay easily. What you have seen there in the link is to just just turnoff few configurations such as second level caching etc.

Comment: Those properties don't actually turn off hibernate... they are just configuration options to change how hibernate performs, and looking at them I personally wouldn't change those settings with out good reason. You'll have to read up on them in the hibernate documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To what extent does it depend on it?

To the fullest possible extent. Since, all the portlets in liferay use hibernate internally to talk to the database.

> Can it be unplugged?

Nope. Not possible.

> How much development effort would be required on it?

See above answer. :-). But still if you think you can somehow do it by building the portal yourself from source, that would be a maintenance headache and what would you do about upgrades ...?

> For what purpose does liferay use its internal database?

The database stores all the information regarding the portal and its OOTB portlets: like Users, Roles, Permissions, PortletPreferences & PortalPreferences and so on ...

I would suggest give special attention to @fvu's comments (the first one).