# Using Liferay DB through Hibernate or JDBC

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, liferay

What is the impact of using Hibernate to connect to Liferay DB Schema?
or What if we use seperate JDBC (can even be Spring JDBC) to connect to custom portlet's application DB Schema?

Also, if we can do it, how to go about it?

Comment: Connecting to liferay DB from liferay or from your custom plugin portlet or from some other web-application outside liferay? Or is this question by any chance somewhat similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11844579/468763

Comment: Connecting to liferay db from custom plugin portlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default hibernate is used to connect to Liferay. And if you use hibernate then you get all the benefit of using ... well Hibernate API :-) which gives you Transaction support and a rich API to generate database agnostic sql queries and more.

For your custom plugin portlet you can also use Liferay's [Service Builder](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Service+Builder), which is nothing but a wrapper around Hibernate and Spring and provides a lot of auto-generated code.

But still if you want to go the other way, then you can use JDBC (or Spring JDBC) the same way for your custom plugin portlet as you do with any other web-application. The configuration remains the same.